# Parquet/arrow: Filtering on a column of (a list of) flags

Tags: r, list, dplyr, parquet, nested-lists

I am working in R, applying dplyr pipelines to large-ish Parquet files (hundreds of GB) in R. One of the columns contains lists of flags (mostly for data issues at the row level).

I want to filter or group the dataset based on the presence/absence combinations of certain strings in this list. Ideally, I would like to do so from within the dplyr pipeline; but since Parquet datasets don't support all the methods (`unnest` for example, and `%in%`), this might not be possible - in which case I'll work with batches of rows in dataframes.

For a small example, consider the Parquet file (or the data frame) created by

```
library(dplyr)
library(arrow)

example_data <- tibble(
  i=c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14),
  flags=list(
    list(),
    list("QUESTIONABLE"),
    list("MANUALLY_CHECKED", "QUESTIONABLE"),
    NULL,
    list("QUESTIONABLE", "UNRELATEDFLAG")
  )
)

write_parquet(example_data, "withlistcol.parquet")
example_data %>% unnest(flags, keep_empty=T)
```

and re-read with

```
ds <- open_dataset("withlistcol.parquet")
```

How do I filter the subset of rows of `ds` that have the flag "MANUALLY_CHECKED" or don't have the flag "QUESTIONABLE"?

Readability is more important to me than performance.

Answer (score 0):

For the multiple partitions, I filter each parquet files after reading it.

```
readparquetR(pathtoread="../example_data", format="parquet", where="flag=='MANUALLY_CHECKED'")
```

The function read it with lapply and uses data.table to filter it. something like this

```
if(nchar(where)>0){             
eval(parse(text=paste0("df=df[",where,"]")))
}
```

works for me when I read partitioned big files
}